# Ado.Net DBase driver truncates cells with tab character

Tags: c#, ado.net, foxpro, dbf, dbase

I am trying to access to an old DBase file with Ado.Net C#. I successfully opened file but some string records in table has TAB character like "Some text/TABOther text". Ado.Net driver successfully reads "Some text" and can not read rest of the data. Is there are a way to let Ado.Net read all the content of the cell?

My connection string:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=DATA DIRECTORY;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=;Password=;";
```

Select query:

```
var sql = "select * from " + "MY_TABLE";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
                con.Open();
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: I would try the Visual FoxPro OLEDB driver maybe, instead of the Jet one.

Answer (score 2):

I would use VFPOLEDB driver from Microsoft.Jet driver is good for maybe dBase II but not trustable for the later versions (like dBase IV).

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
new OleDbAdapter("select * from MY_TABLE",
  "Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=DATA DIRECTORY",
).Fill(tbl);
```

And be sure you only have TAB character in between. While xbase databases can store any character in a string field, in C# (contrary to documentation) strings are ASCIIZ strings like in C. Also if that string has NEWLINE character in it, in DataTable you might not see that.

PS: Try posting to Visual-Foxpro tag next time. That one has more interest.